# PDO_OCI prepare/execute

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, oracle11g

I'm trying to figure out why my pdo_oci execute/prepare statements aren't working. It might be something trivial that I'm missing or oci drivers them selves or I don't even know anymore ...
Short description: there's one query, array of parameters to be inserted.

```
try{
    $conn = new PDO($dsn,$db_username,$db_password);
}catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo ($e->getMessage());
}

$statement = 'INSERT INTO "statements" ("modelID", "subject", "predicate", "object", "l_language", "author", "stread", "stedit", "stdelete", "epoch")
                VALUES  (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, sysdate)';
$params = array(8, 
'http://192.168.1.234/taooracle/tao_ora_dev.rdf#i1386245617410387',
'http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#label',
'Item 8',
'en-US',
'http://192.168.1.234/taooracle/tao_ora_dev.rdf#superUser',
'yyy[admin,administrators,authors]',
'yyy[admin,administrators,authors]',
'yyy[admin,administrators,authors]'
);

//test if $conn works
$result = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM "statements"');
if($result->fetch() > 0){
    echo 'PDO connection works' ."<br/>";
}
if(count($params) > 0){
    $sth = $conn->prepare($statement);  
    $sth->execute($params);
    $returnValue = $sth->rowCount();
}
echo 'Affected rows: '. $returnValue;

    **RESULTS:**
    PDO connection works
    Affected rows: 0

    EDIT: statements table column names/types
create table statements
(
  "modelID"    NUMBER(11),
  "subject"    VARCHAR2(255),
  "predicate"  VARCHAR2(255),
  "object"     VARCHAR2(4000),
  "l_language" VARCHAR2(255),
  "id"         NUMBER(20) not null,
  "author"     VARCHAR2(255),
  "stread"     VARCHAR2(255),
  "stedit"     VARCHAR2(255),
  "stdelete"   VARCHAR2(255),
  "epoch"      DATE
)
```

id is inserting by trigger, on very insert statement. (this really doesn't matter because simple queries with pdo->exec() statement works and they use same table/cols).

**EDIT: MY ANSWER**
Had to change '?' to some valid string. Don't know why oracle throws exception that it's invalid character.

In case anybody else has this issue, I found out what was causing it. Class I was using to generate queries, was appending semicolon to the end of queries. This didn't seem to bother MySQL, but it failed Oracle. So I just added if clause for pdo_oci driver, to remove semicolons if found.

Comment: **$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,  PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);** place this code in the try block and tell what you get now?

Comment: I originally had this PDO::_ERRMODE setup, but for some reason it didn't seem to work with oracle, but now that I tried it I got valid oracle sql error, should be able to fix it. thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Now that's interesting, while using prepare(...VALUES(?,?,?...) oracle says that ? is invalid character, but shouldn't execute($params) replace all question marks with values specified in $params array?